# replacing strings in file with values from a list in batch

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I have a simple problem, yet I am struggling for some days now to get a simple batch skript running. All I want to do, is to loop through a list (e.g. `123,456,789`) and replace the first and second occurence of a string in a file with `123`, and the next two occurences with `456` and so on...

So this content of a file:

```
xyz
foo xyz
foo xyz
xyz
xyz foo xyz
xyz foo xyz
xyz
foo xyz
foo xyz
xyz
```

Looks somthing like this afterwards:

```
xyz
123 xyz
123 xyz
xyz
xyz 456 xyz
xyz 456 xyz
xyz
789 xyz
789 xyz
xyz
```

I tried chatGPT, but since I am a batch noob and I have no idea what I am doing wrong, this is all I got:

```bash
@echo off
set "infile=replaceTest.sql"
set "outfile=replaceTest_out.sql"
set SEARCH=foo
set LIST=123,456,789
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(
    for %%i in (%LIST%) do (
        set REPLACE=%%i
        set /a count=0  
        for /f "delims=" %%A in ('"findstr /n ^^ %infile%"') do (
            set "line=%%A"
            set "line=!line:*:=!"
            (echo !line! | findstr /i /c:%SEARCH% >nul) && (set /a count+=1)
            if !count! LSS 3 (
                REM set LINE=!LINE:%SEARCH%=%REPLACE%!
                set "line=!line:foo=bar!"
            )
            echo(!line!
        )
    ) > "%outfile%"
)
```

But this only replaces the first two...

and the line `REM set LINE=!LINE:%SEARCH%=%REPLACE%!` only replaces the `foo` with nothing *(which is why it is commented out here)*.

Comment: In order to offer better advice, I'd like to see representative real world examples, of your list and file content. You are not really using `xyz`, `foo`, `123`, `456`, `789` etc. and as batch files flakey with certain characters, and some file encoding and line ending types, batch files are not recommended for performing this type of task. As you have no idea what you are doing, you may not be able to modify any solution to your real intent, post answer, especially with the forementioned problems with your chosen scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a `for` command to process the `%LIST%` elements because each element must pass to the next one based on *other factors* (`if` command).

You have not specified what happens if there are more replacements than LIST elements.

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "infile=test.txt"
set "outfile=output.txt"
set "SEARCH=foo"
set "LIST=123,456,789"
set "TIMES=2"
set "count=0"

for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%x in ("%LIST%") do (
   set "REPLACE=%%x"
   set "LIST=%%y"
)

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%infile%"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line (
      for %%r in ("!REPLACE!") do set "newline=!line:%SEARCH%=%%~r!"
      if "!newline!" neq "!line!" (
         set "line=!newline!"
         set /A count+=1
         if !count! equ %TIMES% (
            for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%x in ("!LIST!") do (
               set "REPLACE=%%x"
               set "LIST=%%y"
               if not defined LIST set "LIST=missing"
            )
            set "count=0"
         )
      )
   )
   echo(!line!
)) > "%outfile%"
```

Each time than a replacement is done (when `line` and `newline` are different) the `count` is incremented. When the `count` reach the number of allowed replacements (`2` in this case) the `REPLACE` value is taken from the next `LIST` element.

You could eliminate the `newline` variable and replace the `if "!newline!" neq "!line!" (` command by `if "!line!" neq "%%b" (`

You could also rearrange the code so the process of LIST variable in the `for /F` command be done just once; this eliminate REPLACE variable and produce slightly simpler code. Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "infile=test.txt"
set "outfile=output.txt"
set "SEARCH=foo"
set "LIST=123,456,789"
set "TIMES=2"
set "count=0"

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%infile%"') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   if defined line (
      for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%x in ("!LIST!") do (
         set "line=!line:%SEARCH%=%%x!"
         if "!line!" neq "%%b" (
            set /A count+=1
            if !count! equ %TIMES% (
               set "count=0"
               set "LIST=%%y"
               if not defined LIST set "LIST=missing"
            )
         )
      )
   )
   echo(!line!
)) > "%outfile%"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q75615698.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

set "SEARCH=foo"
set "LIST=123,456,789"
SET /a count=0
SET /a listindex=1

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 IF "%%e"=="!line:%search%=!" (ECHO %%e) ELSE (
  SET /a listcount=0
  FOR %%r IN (%list%) DO IF DEFINED line (
   SET /a listcount+=1
   IF !listcount!==!listindex! (
    ECHO !line:%search%=%%r!
    SET /a count+=1
    IF !count!==2 SET /a count=0&SET /a listindex+=1
    SET "line="
   )
  )
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

rem **Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

Hmm - [ChatGPT is banned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) but I believe that it's actually *answers* generated by ChatGPT - and this question demonstrates why.

Leaving aside the artificial nature of the source text, the approach is questionable.

For each line in the source,

- reproduce it if it doesn't contain the search string otherwise,
- find the replacement string which is the `listindex`th entry in `list`, echo the string with substitution and count 1 substitution. If we've made 2, reset the count an select the next `listindex`. Clear `line` so that the `for %%r`'s actions are disabled until the next line is read from the source.